# Can I factor out or statements on the other side of an equation in boolean?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have this boolean equation:

```
X'Y'+XY+X'Y=X'+Y
```

I want to prove it.

Now I was wondering if I can rearrange this equation, if I could, so I can factor out the other side; tell me if this is allowed. I haven't seen anything to say I could in my textbook:

```
X'Y'+XY+X'Y
```

`X'Y'+X'Y+XY`              see now I move the X'Y to the left

```
X'(Y+Y')+XY

X'+X'Y+XY

X'+Y(X'+X)

X'+Y
```

Am I doing it right? I've been trying this equation in other ways and haven't been able to prove it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all of your rearrangements are correct, except it is not clear how you get from $X'(Y+Y')+XY$ to $X'+X'Y+XY$. I would write your argument like this:
$$\begin{split}X'Y'+XY+X'Y&=X'Y'+X'Y+XY\\
&=X'(Y'+Y)+XY\\
&=X'(1)+XY\\
&=X'+XY\\
&=(X'+X)(X'+Y)\\
&=(1)(X'+Y)\\
&=X'+Y.\end{split}$$

Comment: Are there any specific limitations to factoring in boolean? Can I factor out of 3+ statements or any part of the expression?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "factoring"? Because I would call what you have done "simplifying". You can certainly simplify boolean expressions that have 3+ terms.

Comment: To help me understand: could you tell me what you see in $X'Y'+XY+X'Y$ that makes you want to get $X'+Y$ rather than $X+Y$?

Comment: It's a proof that you can get to that. Factoring as in pulling alike terms out of the multiples.

Comment: OK, I see. When you are working in boolean you can factor in two different ways: $X_1Y+X_2Y+\dotsb +X_nY=(X_1+\dotsb +X_n)Y$ and $(X_1X_2\dotsm X_n)+Y=(X_1+Y)(X_2+Y)\dotsm(X_n+Y)$ for any number of $X_1,X_2,\dotsc,X_n$.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got from `X' + XY` to `(X'+X)(X'+Y)` As for me, there's a formula where `C'+CD = C'+D`. It's in the book I am using, you can expand the C' and then use that to eliminate the A.

Comment: To get from $X'+XY$ to $(X'+X)(X'+Y)$ I am using [distributive law (b)](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/boolalgebra/#distributivelaw) with $A=X'$, $B=X$ and $C=Y$. The formula in your book is a rule that you can most certainly use, I am just breaking down the steps of how you _prove_ that formula.